# Granting access to IIS 7.5 ApplicationPoolIdentity

Tags: authorization, iis-7.5

When I try to access my ASP.NET MVC application I get the error:

```
Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\website\bin\test.Platform.Config.xml' is denied
```

I run IIS 7.5 with an application pool that has the property:

```
Identity: ApplicationPoolIdentity
```

I imagine it is because the 'ApplicationPoolIdentity' cannot read the file I try to access. So my question is: Since the 'ApplicationPoolIdentity' is not a system user, which user or group do I need to grant further access in order to allow the 'ApplicationPoolIdentity' to read the file?

Or is there some other explanation for this authorization problem?

Comment: The procedure is the same as IIS7: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7334485/2291

Answer (score 67):

Ok I have the solution:

When using "ApplicationPoolIdentity" with IIS 7.5 the corresponding user is (a virtual system user):

```
"IIS AppPool\<AppPoolName>"
```

You can grant this user permissions and check security setting by searching for this user. See the full explanation here:

http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

Comment: How to force this changes to be applied? I made this and still no effect.

Comment: Same, this is horribly frustrating.  I've done everything Microsoft said to do and I still get a warning on Authorization.

Comment: From the File Explorer's Security tab, when searching for the app pool user to add, I had to change the **From this location** field from the domain directory to the local machine name. This answer helped me to realize that so thanks!