# Solving error "The configuration section 'aspNetCore' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration"

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am configuring IIS 7.0 on windows server 2008 R2 to run the new .net Core framework and I am getting this error:

> *The configuration section 'aspNetCore' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration*

Is there a setting I need to implement to get this type of site to run?
applicationpool identity is used.

The web.config is automatically scripted with this tag from VS 2015 community.

Here is the config after it is compiled and published:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <!--
    Configure your application settings in appsettings.json. Learn more at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=786380
  -->
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\HUBS.dll" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 6f683ac9-2a86-4206-b3fe-8d5705488733-->
```

Comment: Did you install the server runtime on the server?

Comment: And did you make sure that the app pool your application runs in is configured to use .NET 4, not .NET 2?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to configure IIS 7.0 (WS 2008 R2) to work with .NET CORE at this time.  I tried again on windows server 2012 IIS 8.0 with much better results...

The application pool in both servers was set up the same way with different results. The app pool .NET CLR is set to No Managed Code, integrated pipeline and ApplicationPoolIdentity.

The ApplicationPoolIdentity has to have file permission for the site directories.
[Granting access to IIS 7.5 ApplicationPoolIdentity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461186/granting-access-to-iis-7-5-applicationpoolidentity)

Maybe this will be fixed in the future.
Good Luck!