# Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. ora-12154 in connecting OraServer in SSIS using Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio, ssis, visual-studio-2013

I want to connect the OraServer in the SSIS using Visual Studio. But the error encountered is **Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. ora-12154 TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified.**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duYOd.png)

And I already download the Oracle Developer Tools For Visual Studio 2013 and ODTwithODAC121024

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1icpN.png)

May I know the cause and the possible solution for this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [Does this help you?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7176252/16764901)

Comment: It would probably be best to somehow get a screenshot into your question, instead of a link, if possible.